# How can I detach an event listener from cloned collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working around search models inside collection.
For prevent fetching collection at all queries I made `collection.clone()`

```
var filteredContacts = contactsCollection.clone();
filteredContacts.reset(filteredContacts.filter(function(contact) {
   if(contact.get("login"))
        return contact.get("login").search(new RegExp(Value, "i")) >= 0;
    else
        return false;
}));
filteredContacts.each(function(contact) {
    new ContactView( { model: contact } );
});
```

also there is listenTo in contactsCollection

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(Backbone, "contacts:open", this.getContacts);
},
```

which make an fetch contacts from server.
So when I try to trigger this event both of those collections catch this event.

How can I call enything like collection.destory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone provides us a function `stopListening()`. This method actually tells an object to stop listening to events.
In your case we can proceed like this

```js
var filteredContacts = contactsCollection.clone();
filteredContacts.reset(filteredContacts.filter(function(contact) {
   if(contact.get("login"))
        return contact.get("login").search(new RegExp(Value, "i")) >= 0;
    else
        return false;
}));
filteredContacts.stopListening("contacts:open");
filteredContacts.each(function(contact) {
    new ContactView( { model: contact } );
});
```

Even there is listenTo in contactsCollection like below

```js
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(Backbone, "contacts:open", this.getContacts);
},
```